# Getting this error Received unknown parameter: unit_amount" when updating product price

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, stripe-payments

I am using this function for updating the price, When I am updating the price getting `Received unknown parameter: unit_amount`.

```
stripe.prices.update(
        setUPFee_Id,
        {
          unit_amount: setUpAmount,
        },
        function (err, price) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err, "err");
          } else {
            console.log(price);
          }
        }
      );
```

Comment: Accpet the answer when it actually answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the `unit_amount` of a `price`. You can achieve it (by setting its `active` to false) and create a new `price` with the new `unit_amount`.

Refer the to [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/update#update_price) for more details